# fetch new and modified record from a Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to MS SQL. I have 2 tables, one has Data and other keeps track of records that were processed (log Table). I want to fetch records that are new i.e not present in log Table and those records that were modified after the last fetch.

I store fetched Date, update Date and Primary Key of the Record from Data Table in my Log Table.

Currently I am doing this by using UNION. 1st query fetches new records and second fetched modified record. Is this the right way to do it or else is there a better way for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `UNION` is actually the best way to get this data, specially if you can use indexes on each select statement

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select id, updatedDate
from YourDataTable
except
select id, updatedDate
from YourLogTable
```

What [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) does it return the rows that aren't in both queries.  INTERSECT does the opposite.

You could also utilize [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), but in my opinion your easiest bet is through `EXCEPT`.